# Source and run custom Office ribbon commands from local static files

Tags: office-js

I am trying to write some personal scripts to manipulate Office Word from commands triggered from a custom ribbon using the Office JS API. Is there a way to source and load these commands from local files (HTML and JS), as opposed to having to serve them from a local or remote server?

These commands are for my personal use and would like to find the shortest path to a nice looking personal ribbon tab without having to run a server locally every time I want to run something.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not at all built for it (at this stage, at any rate), I wonder if [Script Lab](https://aka.ms/scriptlab) might serve your needs.  It wouldn't be a ribbon, but a task one to launch the commands -- but I'd be keen to hear your experience with the tool...

Comment: Thanks. I have tried Script Lab and its very useful for development but not quite what I need for a steady state personal add-in. On a side note, it would be very very cool if one could use VS Code to develop add-in directly. Seems that would be the ideal editor for this.

Comment: If  you want to describe more of what you mean -- both the limitations of what you'd ideally see in Script Lab, and what your ideal grow-up / VS Code  scenario would entail, please file a suggestion issue on https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/issues